# Text manipulation basic Java

Tags: java

So I have a text document in a format like this:

```
80  Egypt           12  1   0   0   13  0
81  Qatar           7   4   1   1   13  0
```

I would like to read it in line by line and store the name of the country along with the highest number (which will always be the 5th number.

However, when I do the following then I am getting an array out of bounds error because it isn't splitting the line up at all.

```
     String st;
     while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] temp = st.split(" ");

     System.out.println(temp[1]);

     }
```

edit:
reason is that they are tabs not spaces and can be fixed with:

```
st.replace("\t", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the case the file has tabs instead of spaces

Comment: what do I do to get rid of tabs

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough context but from my own experience I'm guessing that your file has one or two empty lines in it (most likely the beginning or the end). Just double check to make sure that the last line has text on it. br.readline() could return an empty String[] if it reads an empty line.

Comment: There are no empty lines. If I make it temp[0] then it will just respond with the same string as originally input. It is not splitting up the string based on the white space.

Comment: then you probably have the wrong regex. String after = before.trim().replaceAll(" +", " "); will remove all the duplicate spaces. Then you can use .split()

Comment: It turns out it's a space instead of a tab, thanks for your time Roshan

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for empty lines just to be safe and split by `\\s+` because the lines contain multiple adjacent spaces.
If there are tabs split by `\\t+`:

```
String st;
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
    st = st.trim();
    if (!st.isEmpty()) {
        String[] temp = st.split("\\s+");
        .........................
    }
}
```